# Is it possible to keep user logged in on device with SQFLITE?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to save bool isLoggedIn in local database sqflite on device. Is it possible? Or maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: I would suggest using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Comment: A better solution is Hive database. Don't go with shared_preferences as it's meant for single values not objects.

Comment: Thanks for Hive advice, it is way easier than sqflite, I will like some of your posts